# Exchange information between my app and a website. SHOPPING CART APP with limited stock products

Tags: parsing, url, paypal, web, cart

I am working on an app for a clothing shop, as you may guess it displays pictures of products, their price, adds them to check out (pay through PayPal ) and more ... but I run into a problem when it comes to pay: I have a limited number of products and I can not let users buy as many products as they want.

I can limit their purchases statically, adding a property called `STOCK` in the product class in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
ProductsData *product11 = [[ProductosData alloc]initWithNombre:@"Table" foto:@"Foto11.jpg" price:number1 number:@"0" cell:cero description:@"This is a table" stock:@"3"];
```

But this is not a real option (multiple users can purchase / every time the app launches the stock count is renewed / ... )

1. How to design/write a website/URL where I can get the info from (info: stock (NSSTRING) or even better: the whole product class).
2. How to get that info into my app (async).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone has the same problem:

I start asking the database :

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://www.yourURL/"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"1000" forKey:@"accion"]; // acción = 1000 -> get all data from mySQL
[request setDelegate:self]; // to get the data
[request startSynchronous];
```

My PHP ( for this call ) sends all the data back ( stock and id of every product ) to my app.

I receive and process the info in the following function:

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
  {

  ```
  NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
  NSLog(@"responseString : %@",responseString);

  NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
  NSLog(@"responseDict : %@",responseDict);

  NSArray *array_ids=[responseDict objectForKey:@"ids"];
  NSArray *array_stocks=[responseDict objectForKey:@"stocks"];

  for (int u=0; u<[array_stocks count]; u++) 
  {

      NSString *id_producto =     [array_ids objectAtIndex:u];
      NSString *stock_producto =  [array_stocks objectAtIndex:u];
    //  NSString *etiqueta_producto= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"producto%@",id_producto];



      int g;

      for (g=0; g<[arrayProductos count]; g++) 
      {
          NSLog(@" arrayProductos.id :%@ id_producto: %@",((ProductosData *)[arrayProductos objectAtIndex:g]).id_producto,id_producto );

          if ( [((ProductosData *)[arrayProductos objectAtIndex:g]).id_producto  intValue]==[id_producto  intValue]) 
          {
              ProductosData* producto =[[ProductosData alloc]init];
              producto=[arrayProductos objectAtIndex:g];
              producto.stockReal=stock_producto;
              [arrayProductos replaceObjectAtIndex:g withObject:producto];
              NSLog(@" nombre: %@ stock: %@ \n", producto.nombreProducto,producto.stockReal);
          }
      }



  }
  ```

> [self GuardarTodo];
>
> // another function where I save all the data in order to be use
>   lately.
>
> }

Now i am trying to figure out how to get, from the data base, the whole class ProductoData ( where I store all the info for every product ) to be able to change products dynamically.

I do not know if I made myself understood, let me know if anything is needed.